# Handling Multiple Changes To Different Objects In An Array Using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I am creating a Discord Bot using discord.js and typescript. I am creating a leveling system where you get XP for sending messages.

I am using mongoose to interact with my database, hosted by MongoDB.

Here is the code for my schema:

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

interface IGuildProfiles {
    guildid: number;
    levels: {
        userid: number;
        totalXp: number;
        level: number;
        levelXp: number;
        levelXpNeeded: number;
        obtained: { level: number; date: number }[];
    }[];
}

const guildProfiles = new Schema<IGuildProfiles>(
    {
        guildid: {type: Number, required: true},
        levels: [
            {
                userid: {type: Number, required: true},
                totalXp: {type: Number, required: true},
                level: {type: Number, required: true},
                levelXp: {type: Number, required: true},
                levelXpNeeded: {type: Number, required: true},
                obtained: [{ level: {type: Number, required: true}, date: {type: Number, required: true} }],
            },
        ],
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

export default model("GuildProfiles", guildProfiles);
```

This creates a document containing a guild ID, and an array of information regarding the level of each user in the guild.

There is nothing wrong with this, but on the event that the bot makes multiple writes to the same guild document at the same time, would this have an unintended side effect of skipping XP sometimes, or is there nothing to worry about?

What I'm worried about:

```
// First Write (Around the same time as other writes)
const data = getDataSomeHow() // {id: 123, example:[]}
writeDataSomeHow() // writes {id:123, example: [{exampleString:"THIS IS THE FIRST WRITE"}]}

// Second Write (Around the same time as other writes)
const data = getDataSomeHow() // {id: 123, example:[]}
writeDataSomeHow() // writes {id:123, example: [{exampleString:"THIS IS THE SECOND WRITE"}]}

// Third Write (Around the same time as other writes)
const data = getDataSomeHow() // {id: 123, example:[]}
writeDataSomeHow() // writes {id:123, example: [{exampleString:"THIS IS THE THIRD WRITE"}]}

// Checking the written data
const data = getDataSomeHow()
/* What I think the data will be because of the side effect:
{id:123, example: [{exampleString:"THIS IS THE THIRD WRITE"}]}

What I want the data to be:
{id:123, example: [{exampleString:"THIS IS THE FIRST WRITE"}, {exampleString:"THIS IS THE SECOND WRITE"}, {exampleString:"THIS IS THE THIRD WRITE"}]}
*/
```

Is this bound to happen, or am I wrong? If it is going to happen, how can I avoid it?

Comment: That really depends on how `writeDataSomeHow()` is written.  Simultaneous updates is a situation that has been handled many different ways.

Comment: @Joe Ok, good to know, any idea how I should write the data?

Comment: You could try using [$inc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#-inc)

Comment: [$push](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push) for appending to an array